# How to add contour to sqrt symbol?

Tags: math-mode, contour

I'm using the contour package to add an outline to an equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contournumber{64}
\contourlength{.1em}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{black}{\boldmath
    \contour{white}{%
        $\displaystyle\int\sqrt{\tan(x)}dx$
    }
}

\end{document}
```

This code is producing the following result:

[image]

Not only the `sqrt` overline seems to be unaffected by the contour but the whole `sqrt` also seems to be unaffected by the boldmath command. How to fix this?

---

I have noticed the `bar` and `widebar` commands interact just fine with both the contour and the boldmath command. Is there a way to switch the `sqrt` overline for one of those?

Comment: The thing on top is a rule and not a glyph.

Comment: please always provide complete small documents, the exact behaviour here depends on the fonts used and it just makes it easier for people to test answers. But as mikep says you would need to draw two rules.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have updated the question to include complete documents. I'm sorry but I don't really understand the solution you are proposing.

Answer (score 5):

TeX draws the square root with a glyph for the tick at the start but the over bar is a rule drawn directly not using a font.  You can draw two wide rules to get close

[image]

You could adjust the spacing a bit more to make it nicer or you could draw the entire radical in something like tikz

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contournumber{64}
\contourlength{.1em}

\begin{document}

$$
\colorbox{black}{\boldmath
    \contour{white}{%
      $\displaystyle\int \sqrt{\strut\smash{%
          \color{white}\vbox{\hrule height.95pt\vskip.4pt\hrule height.95pt \vskip2.7pt
            \hbox{$\color{black}\tan(x)$}}}}dx$
    }
}
$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Why do you use double $$ :-)?